# TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"] Video 144. Testing with Authentication

Tags: node.js, jestjs

this a exercise from Andrew Meads Complete node.js developer course, the problem seems to be on "set("Authorization",.... any idea how to solve this?

```
   test('Should get profile for user', async () => {
        await request(app)
            .get('/users/me')
            .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userOne.tokens[0].token}`)
            .send()
            .expect(200)
    })
```

Complete error:

```
      FAIL  tests/user.test.js
      ● Should get profile for user
    
        TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]
    
          at Test.request (node_modules/superagent/src/node/index.js:834:39)
          at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Request.end (node_modules/superagent/src/node/index.js:956:8)
          at Test.end (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:118:11)
          at node_modules/superagent/src/request-base.js:285:12
          at Test.Object.<anonymous>.RequestBase.then (node_modules/superagent/src/request-base.js:267:31)
```

Comment: So what _is_ `userOne.tokens[0].token`?

Comment: const userOneId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()  
const userOne = {  
    _id: userOneId,  
    name: 'Mike',  
    email: 'mike@example.com',  
    password: '56what!!',  
    tokens: [{  
        token: jwt.sign({ _id: userOneId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET)  
    }]  
}

it came from here, actually there was a typo in that object and that solved my problem, thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.